# How To Handle Composition/Aggregation and Polymorphism in Java

Tags: java, oop

I have two abstract classes, lets call them `Car`'s and `Wheel`'s. I am handling different types of cars using some inheritance. So lets say there are two derivations `MonsterTruckCar` and `ToyCar`. Additionally there are different types of wheels that correspond to the `Car`s, say `TreadedWheel`'s and `PlasticWheel`'s (the mapping does not necessarily need to be one-to-one from types of cars to types of wheels). Further `Car`'s are composed of `Wheel`'s.

The way I thought I would be able to do this in Java is by using an attribute of `Car`'s to be type `ArrayList<Wheel>`. The issue I am having is that now when I want to use polymorphism on the `Wheel`'s I cannot because whenever I deal with a Wheel it is through an `ArrayList` which is not a derived class of `Wheel`'s.

I thought I might be able to use bounded wildcards, or just a lot of switch statements to handle different combinations but I dont think either of those would be the greatest solutions. How can I handle such a structure?

Further, how do you add `Wheel`'s to the composition/collection in `Car`'s. That is, I need to be able to add a variable amount of concrete `Wheel`'s to a `Car`, further this is going to be based off of some user input. so I would like to have a while loop in the default constructor that prompt the user if he/she wants to add another wheel and then if he/she does I add another `Wheel` to whatever is aggregating/collecting them in `Car`'s.

Edit: Edited the names of the classes themselves from plural (`Wheels`) to singular with a 's (`Wheel`'s) to clarify the relationship. Added the last paragraph which explains further the behavior I am looking for.

Comment: The part about 'ArrayList is not a derived class' seems so wrong. The elements in the list are all `Wheel`s isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a generic parameter to your Car class that specified the wheel type. Here's a very basic implementation you can build on:

#### Edited:

Includes updated requirements, which is tricky, but doable...

```
public interface Wheel {
    void setSize(int diameter);
}

public static abstract class Car<T extends Wheel> {

    private List<T> wheels = new ArrayList<T>();

    protected Car(int numberOfWheels, Class<T> wheelClass) {
        while (wheels.size() < numberOfWheels) {
            T wheel;
            try {
                wheel = wheelClass.newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e); // simplified exception handling
            }
            wheel.setSize(5); // Ask user for wheel details etc
            wheels.add(wheel);
        }
    }

    public List<T> getWheels() {
        return wheels;
    }
}

public static class PlasticWheel implements Wheel { // or extends Wheel
    @Override
    public void setSize(int diameter) {
    }
}

public static class ToyCar extends Car<PlasticWheel> {
    public ToyCar() {
        super(6, PlasticWheel.class); // or you could pass number of wheels in to this constructor
    }
}

public static class TreadedWheel implements Wheel { // or extends Wheel

    @Override
    public void setSize(int diameter) {
    }
}

public static class MonsterTruckCar extends Car<TreadedWheel> {
    public MonsterTruckCar() {
        super(4, TreadedWheel.class); // or you could pass number of wheels in to this constructor
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 this is a high quality concise answer, but I refined and added to the question slightly. Before I accept I would appreciate if you could clarify a little further. Thanks!

Comment: The problems with this kind of design start when you have more than one type that need to be generic: Car<W extends Wheel, S extends Seat, D extends Driver, G extends Gearbox, M extends Motor> ...